# Iterating through dom nodes using a map method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, phantomjs, web-crawler, casperjs

so I was basically crawling a table in a website, and I saved that table in an object.

While trying to iterate through the object, I wanted to gather different table cells that had a  tag in one object so I created the following code:

```
listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    return [].map.call(nodes, function(node, index, arr) {
      var userObject = {
      nom: node.innerText,
      prenom: arr[index + 1].innerText
    }
    return userObject;
 });
});
```

So basically the "Index + 1" returns a Null for some reason

Comment: For the last object index+1 isn't a valid index of the array JavaScript then returns null

Comment: So are you saying it *always* returns `null` or just on the last iteration?

Comment: It actually always returns null.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the arr[index + 1]  part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last object index+1 isn't a valid index of the array JavaScript then returns null

Comment: It seems to be the case. But why isn't it a valid index though?

Comment: The last index is the highest index in the array so you can't add 1. You just check if you are at the last item and then just return.